# How to open python GUI straight from the desktop? (instead of going through wing101 and running the script)

Tags: python, macos, user-interface

I want to be able to click a shortcut from my desktop, and it open a GUI i have written in my script. Im using tkinter through wing101 on a mac, and am very new here.

Comment: You save it as a `.py` file, mark it executable and double-click it. How shortcuts work in OSX.. I have no idea.. But idealy OSX will handle Python as it's interpreter based on the file ending.

Comment: http://www.pyinstaller.org/ works good to create executables from python scripts.

Comment: Use `chmod` to mark the script as executable and make sure you have a proper shebang comment (like `#!/usr/bin/env python`) at the beginning of the file.